# connect to wifi from console without retry on wrong pwd

Tags: command-line, network-manager

I'm currently trying to have a c++ software to connect to a network.

I use nmcli to connect to the network, and it works perfectly fine.

The issue is, if the pwd given to the software for a network is incorrect, then nmcli start a prompt (or new console line with `--ask`) requiring user input, thus making the soft hang.

Is there a tool that can allow me to try to connect to network only once (i.e. no console prompt or popup) that simply print an error message in console?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was simplier than I thought.

using the `--wait` option with a bit of tuning for the time prevent the popup.